# Google Maps API v3 select info window as jquery DOM object

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I would like to select a Google Maps info window as a DOM object using jQuery.

```
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
             return function() {
                  var contentString = '<h1>' + addresses[i][0] + '</h1>';
                  infowindow.setContent(contentString);
                  infowindow.open(map, marker);
             }
        })(marker, i));
```

Something like:

```
$(infowindow).addClass('.info-window');
```

How can I select the Google Maps info window DOM element with jQuery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
infowindow.open(map, marker);
$('.gm-style-iw').parent().addClass('info-window');
```

That worked.